# The tag and-engine should be andengine, as it is on SO

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I recently created a question with the tag [and-engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/and-engine). This should not have a hyphen (there is no space, or hyphen in AndEngine) and should be [andengine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andengine), as it is on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/andengine/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and made this change.